# How to get mails In date range?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imap

Work on C#. In my desktop application ,successfully I can Use the 
[IMAP4](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/pythonmagazine/features/mailbox2ics/index.html)  to get  mails from inbox . But Fail to  get mails With in date range.**suppose** want to get mail’s with in range 27-Nov-2011 to 28-Nov-2011. I write bellow syntax but is not work.

```
Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client();
imap.ConnectSsl(sImapHost, nImapPort);
imap.Login(sImapUser, sImapPassword);

inbox = imap.SelectMailbox(@"[Gmail]/Sent Mail");


MessageCollection messages = inbox.SearchParse("SINCE " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

Need help to get mails in date range.

If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using? I'm going to make a wild guess you are using MailSystem.NET? If you you may want to mention that in the question.

Comment: That appears to be a class name, not the library name.  I'm still pretty sure you're using MailSystem.NET.  The class in question is http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63853#541880  so maybe you might want to add the source to your solution, then step through the .SearchParse()

Comment: The link in your question now leads to a python page. Maybe we'd get further if you'd post the text of your error message. It's possible that it isn't the library that doesn't understand the command, but the Gmail IMAP server doesn't understand the command or possibly the date format. When going from C# to an internet standard, its hard to say what the expected date format is.

Comment: MatthewMartin i know my link follow a python page ,but all programming language logic are same.My requirement is not so complex.Just want to know How to get mail with in date range

Comment: MatthewMartin i use ActiveUp.Net.Imap4.dll

Comment: esskar's answered your question. Actually it does matter because IMAP libraries usually provide either a library way to do it, or a pure IMAP command way to do it that might work over, say a telnet connection to the IMAP server. In that case, rfc3501 and gmails IMAP documentation would then be relevant.

Comment: MatthewMartin can u plz tell me if my date formate is ("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") then what to .How to write on query.

Comment: the IMAP spec says times get disregarded. gmails implementation might pay attention to them anyhow, you'd have to experiment or check with gmail docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MessageCollection messages = inbox.SearchParse("SINCE " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

means the mails since today.
but you want them since another time

<strike>var since = new DateTime(2011, 11, 27);</strike>
    <strike>var messages = inbox.SearchParse("SINCE " + since.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));</strike>

**EDIT**

Looked into the [Mailbox.cs](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63853#541807), the syntax is different

```
var messages = inbox.SearchParse("SEARCH SINCE 27-Nov-2011 NOT BEFORE 28-NOV-2011");
```

Comment: esskar thanks for reply.Thanks for your above syntax.My friend i Know about this,but problem is if i want to get mail between 27-Nov-2011 to 28-Nov-2011 then i fail .will you plz tell me how to write query for this purpose.Thanks again

Comment: what does 'fail' mean? do you get an exception? does it not returning anything? please be more detailed!

Comment: I'd use esskar's suggestion and then do a foreach loop through the results to kick out anything above the desired date range.